# How do I allow Nginx to share a Let’s Encrypt certificate used by Apache on the same system?

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl, nginx, wordpress, hls

I run an apache WordPress website on VMbox Debian 10. I have a domain at eu.org and Let’s Encrypt certificate for my domains, so my site is accessible through HTTPS.

I also installed Nginx with RTMP module and setup an HLS (HTTP Live Streaming) stream which is embedded in a post on the website. It works fine when watched with an iPhone but when I try to watch it with a PC or an Android, I get an error saying that the content is mixed meaning that my website runs HTTPS while the stream itself is HTTP.

How do I secure it with HTTPS?

Can I somehow include the Nginx server with the same certificate that I run on Apache though I don’t run any website on Nginx?

Here are the contents of my `nginx.conf` file:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes  auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
load_module modules/ngx_rtmp_module.so;
load_module modules/ngx_stream_module.so;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

# RTMP configuration
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935; # Listen on standard RTMP port
        chunk_size 4000;

        application live {
            live on;
            # Turn on HLS
            hls on;
            hls_path /mnt/hls/;
            hls_fragment 3;
            hls_playlist_length 60;
            # disable consuming the stream from nginx as rtmp
            deny play all;
        }
    }
}

http {
    sendfile off;
    tcp_nopush on;

    directio 512;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    server {
        listen 444 default_server;
    server_name magrega.ru.eu.org;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/magrega.ru.eu.org/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/magrega.ru.eu.org/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

    
        location / {
            # Disable cache
            add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-cache';

            # CORS setup
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length';

            # allow CORS preflight requests
            if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
                add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                return 204;
            }

            types {
                application/dash+xml mpd;
                application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
                video/mp2t ts;
            }

            root /mnt/;
        }
    
}
}user www-data;
worker_processes  auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
load_module modules/ngx_rtmp_module.so;
load_module modules/ngx_stream_module.so;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

# RTMP configuration
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935; # Listen on standard RTMP port
        chunk_size 4000;

        application live {
            live on;
            # Turn on HLS
            hls on;
            hls_path /mnt/hls/;
            hls_fragment 3;
            hls_playlist_length 60;
            # disable consuming the stream from nginx as rtmp
            deny play all;
        }
    }
}

http {
    sendfile off;
    tcp_nopush on;

    directio 512;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    server {
        listen 444 default_server;
    server_name magrega.ru.eu.org;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/magrega.ru.eu.org/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/magrega.ru.eu.org/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

    
        location / {
            # Disable cache
            add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-cache';

            # CORS setup
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length';

            # allow CORS preflight requests
            if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
                add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                return 204;
            }

            types {
                application/dash+xml mpd;
                application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
                video/mp2t ts;
            }

            root /mnt/;
        }
    
}
}
```

Comment: Yes. Read the nginx docs. In fact, you can move the cert completely to nginx.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit? I am still new to this. I entered the path to my certificate in nginx.conf but it still gives me an error.

Comment: @magrega “… though I don’t run any website on Nginx…” You are mixing up website with web service. Apache and Nginx are both web services. In your case you are using Apache for the WordPress site but you are using Nginx for the HLS stuff. To use the same certificate you are using in Apache with Nginx [read up here](https://www.nginx.com/blog/using-free-ssltls-certificates-from-lets-encrypt-with-nginx/); I would recommend skipping all the way down to “If you look at `domain‑name.conf`, you see that certbot has modified it:” and look at that sample config.

Comment: @magrega Please edit your question: Also when you say this, “I entered the path to my certificate in nginx.conf but it still gives me an error.” you should edit your question to add your Nginx config so we can see what you are setting and assist in helping you set this up.

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out thanks to you, guys. I used one of the articles mentioned above.